# How to use stripe in clojurescript?

Tags: stripe-payments, clojurescript

I want to create a token so that I can send that token and create a charge in the server. Following these instructions:

[image]

I add the script tag in my index.html. But in my reagent app, when I use (Stripe. "sdfjasodfhioas"), in my Figwheel project, I get Stripe. undeclared. How do I fix this?

Comment: You may be able to use https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/tree/master/stripe with the caveat that `The Stripe js API will still need to be provided through some other mechanism.` You may also have some luck with checking https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/issues/1213

Answer (score 1):

When you write `(Stripe. "token")` you are referencing a `Stripe` name in the current namespace. But the `Stripe` object is a regular JavaScript object coming from a regular JavaScript library, and thus lives in the special `js` namespace. You might want to try:

```clj
(js/Stripe. "token")
```

Here is a rule of thumb: open your js console and type something like `document`, `History`, `localStorage`, or `Stripe`. If it evaluates to some value, then it's in the `js` namespace.